# TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported using env file with fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

I'm trying to use node-fetch to do a GET request. I'm using dotenv to take the url, but the fetch retrieve me `TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported`, the `URL_ENV` variable isn't undefined

```js
require('dotenv').config();
let url = process.env.URL_ENV;
        fetch(url ,{method: 'GET'}).then(response => {
            return response.json() 
         })
```

If I change the url variable with the content of the `URL_ENV`inside the .env file it works

```js
let url = "http://192.168.1.140:8080"
        fetch(url,{method: 'GET'}).then(response => {
            return response.json()
        })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you clarify you question? What is not working? What behavior do you expect?

Comment: Thanks for you interest. 
I can't understand why putting the same url, in different way,  I have two different behaviors.
I'm expect that also with the env variable, the first snippet of code, the fetch works.

Comment: Have you tried to check value of `process.env.URL_ENV` at run-time? Try to use `Console.log()` or similar method to find out the actual value. As the error says, it must be an absolute URL.

Comment: Yes I have tried, `http://192.168.1.140:8080` is printed

Comment: If the code is not working with `process.env.URL_ENV` and suddenly works when you replace it with string literal `http://192.168.1.140:8080` then there may be some unnecessary characters like spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.?

Comment: ok, thanks, now it's working I think that there was a space in excess

Comment: Somehow related, but it might be possible that `URL_ENV` isn't parsed immediately as an absolute path.

Perhaps resolving the environment variable with `new URL(URL_ENV)` first might resolve the issue.

https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/481#issuecomment-403595704

Answer (score 0):

Do you have commas or semicolon symbols at the end of your lines in .env file? If you do, remove them and it should work

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34567147)